# How small can the Text in a QGraphicsScene get?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm trying to implement my own `QGraphicsItem`s to display in a `QGraphicsScene`. One advantage of this is, that I can keep the positions and sizes of my business objects, without having to convert between them and the display coordinate system.

But: Unfortunately the sizes are small, like 0.5 (meters). This is not a problem with the `QPolygon`s, but when I want to display text at half the size of the objects, below a point or pixel size of 0.5, nothing gets displayed.

I got around that somewhat by having the labels separately created in the scene as `QSimpleTextItem`s and scaling them afterwards, but I don't want that kind of separation.

Am I missing something? Like a way to scale everything times 100 behind the scenes?

Update:

I now also tried scaling the `QPainter` object up, so that I can use more "normal" font sizes, but it seems this does not change the behaviour.

Scaling everything by `100` and then setting the font (point) size to `0.2 * 100`, does also not show the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a `QGraphicsTextItem` object inside my custom `QGraphicsItem` object.

This text object I can scale down to whatever size I need and just call its `paint()` method in the `paint` method of my custom object.

This works pretty well, although I'm not yet sure, if, for example, clicking the text, automatically translates to a click on my custom object, or if they are two separate entities.

I guess it comes down to the bounding rectangle, though.